# Why does address of global variable not change while locals changes in multiple runs?

Tags: c, operating-system, loader, memory-layout

I ran this program multiple times on the same machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 0;
int main() {
  int b = 0;
  printf("%p %p\n", &a, &b);
}
```

1. Every time it is printing the same address of the variable `a` but for `b` it changes. I know `a` will go into the `.data` section so address is fixed (correct me if I am wrong) but why is stack getting a different address every time?
2. All these addresses will be virtual. Is it possible to get the physical address from these variables?
3. If a global variable is initialized to zero, where will it go, BSS or data?

Comment: (1) [ASLR — Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)?  (2) No.  (3) BSS probably, but up to the compiler/linker.

Comment: This question cannot really be answered without you being *specific* about the platform and the compiler in question. You presume very many things that are outside of the C standard: sections, segments, address translation, ... - without a specific platform to speak of, this is all meaningless...

Comment: "Is it possible to get the physical address from these variables?" What for? "will go into the .data section so address is fixed" Who told you that? It's completely platform specific.

Comment: i am running all these test on ideone.com server.

Comment: @KubaOber that's why i asked correct me if i am wrong. so what can be reason for that?

Comment: @RATHI "what can be reason for that?" The reason for what? Again: tell us how you intend to use that information. The "ideone.com" server doesn't mean much. What exact platform is it? (compiler/version/target architecture)

Comment: Just want to know what can be reason of the global variable address coming same in each run ?

Answer (score 2):

1. @JonathanLeffler already mentioned that the stack address changes due to address space layout randomization.

To make the addresses of globals change as well compile your executable with `-fpie` and link with `-fpie -pie`.

See [Position Independent Executables (PIE)](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2012/11/28/position-independent-executables-pie/) for more details.

---

2. Not possible from the user space. Even if you had the physical address that would not be of much use in the user space because it may change due to swap-out-swap-in.

---

3. Normally zero-initialized data goes into BSS.